# Palavras diferentes que evoluem para homônimos. Como se chama este fenômeno linguístico?

Tags: significado, etimologia, português-brasileiro, homofonia

Existe um caso deste tipo bem interessante no português do Brasil: a palavra *Exu*.

É um nome de [entidade de religiões e cultos afro-brasileiros](https://www.raizesespirituais.com.br/orixas/exu/), como de uma [cidade do estado de Pernambuco, Brasil](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exu_(Pernambuco)).

Os termos que originaram o nome *Exu* são oriundos de línguas, culturas e significados diferentes (a primeira, africana; a segunda, indígena), que sofreram modificações ao longo do tempo de forma independente até chegar ao homônimo.

Existe um tratado específico para este processo de "convergência" em linguística e mais particularmente para a língua portuguesa?

Comment: Lembra-me do fenômeno evolutivo em que membros do corpo de animais de origens muito distintas obtêm funções iguais (asa de inseto (artrópode) e asa de morcego (mamífero)): analogia. A pergunta já foi feita em inglês https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164527/is-there-a-term-for-the-convergent-evolution-of-homonyms porém sem resposta satisfatória, ao que tudo indica não há um termo existente para o fenômeno.

Comment: Esse exemplo não funciona porque se trata de nomes próprios. Não de palavras "normais". Nomes própios podem ter mil origens. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nome_próprio Cada um tem sua história. O fato que um nome própio acaba sendo igual que outro é  uma caso fortuito.

Comment: Encontrei um [artigo](http://www.filologia.org.br/anais/anais%20iv/civ03_53-68.html) que não considero exatamente a resposta, mas aborda alguns temas que ajudam a elucidar a questão. Destaco 3 pontos que acho relevantes:  Convergência Fonética, Divergência Semântica, Influência estrangeira.

Comment: Nomes próprios não fazem parte desse assunto.

Comment: @Lambie, a palavra Exu, na origem indígena, origina-se de um termo indígena que não é considerado nome próprio. Analogamente, tem uma cidade no Brasil de nome Ameixas, nome é próprio quando nos referimos à cidade, mas não no caso da fruta. Ainda que Exu na origem africana seja próprio, este caso não cabe uma exceção? O termo Exu é só um exemplo, obviamente deve ter inumeráveis outros de nomes não próprios.

Comment: Por favor, eu não preciso de uma repetição. Ao contrário, preciso que você responda ao meu comentário sobre nomes própios. A origem de nomes própios não tem nada a ver com o estudo etimológico das palavras normais. No caso de homônimos já se sabe a etimologia. Não existe "convergencia". Existem duas palavras separadas quanto ao sentido e origem que têm a mesma forma. Mas elas não convergeram. Ao contrário, o caminho históricos delas são diferentes. Pois, se estuda cada  uma.

Comment: Gwarah, *onça* vem do latim, mas com duas etimologia diferentes: a unidade vem de *uncia* ; o bicho de *lyncea*. Mas não é verdade que todos os homónimos têm etimologias diferentes? Caso contrário não seriam apenas uma mesma palavra com várias aceções? Quando é que são dois homónimos e quando é que são simplesmente uma palavra com duas aceções? Por exemplo, *porca* (bicho e aquilo onde enrosca o parafuso) é o quê? O aulete diz que vem tudo da mesma origem.

Comment: @Jacinto, na maioria dos casos é verdade o que você disse sim. Existem algumas exceções: cana pode significar a planta que produz a aguardente, e pode significar o uso da bebida alcoólica (Ex: o rapaz tomou uma baita _cana_ e dormiu no bar). Mas a segunda teve origem na primeira. Fiz questão de colocar origens bem diferentes inclusive idiomáticas (no caso aí africana e indígena), para mostrar que mesmo assim pode ocorrer esta "convergência linguística". Foi uma boa observação a sua.

Comment: @Lambie, acho que não posso lhe responder, até porque se tivesse a resposta nem formularia esta pergunta. Acho que quando você afirma "Não existe "convergencia". Existem duas palavras separadas quanto ao sentido e origem que têm a mesma forma. Mas elas não convergiram. " você já tem a resposta a minha pergunta, embora eu não concorde exatamente. Só lembro de quando falo em convergência não significa que há necessariamente um fator que traga estes termos distintos em um homônimo. Normalmente é uma coincidência linguística mesmo, exceto em casos como o citado no post anterior (termo cana)

Comment: Concordo com o Jacinto. Ele está dizendo a mesma coisa que eu.

Comment: Acho que quando você diz 'etimologias diferentes' quer dizer origens em línguas diferentes. 'Sessão' e 'seção' são duas palavras homônimas com a mesma origem linguística, enquanto que espiar (gótico) e expiar (latim) são também homônimos de "etimologias" diferentes. É isso a que se refere?

Comment: Exato, ao processo de 2 termos completamente diferentes (no caso aí inclusive de origens linguísticas diferentes), evoluírem para um homônimo comum (no caso Exu, também homógrafo). Se este fenômeno tem um termo na linguística e se tem tratados ou disciplinas específicos para estudá-lo.

Comment: Por sinal corrigi a pergunta conforme você sugeriu, a etimologia não é diferente. O que é diferente é a evolução destes termos. Muito Obrigado @WilliamLio

Comment: Postei uma resposta que talvez atraia atenção para esta thread, e então a de alguém com uma proposição que supere a minha em termos de conhecimento.

Comment: @WilliamLio e gwarah, creio que não estou a acompanhar bem: se duas palavras evoluem de origens diferentes, então têm diferentes etimologias (a etimologia é precisamente a evolução da palavra na forma e significado), O ponto do meu comentário anterior era dar-te um exemplo de homónimos (*onça*) que evitasse a controvérsia dos nomes próprios; e sugerir que a palavra para esse par de palavras que resulta da convergência **poderá** ser simplesmente *homónimos* (depende de *homonimía* implicar ou não origens diferentes).

Comment: Gwarah, encontrei um par perfeito para as tuas necessidades, dois substantivos comuns com origem em línguas completamente separadas: [*manga*](http://www.aulete.com.br/manga) 'parte de roupa' vem do latim *manica*; *manga* 'fruto' vem do malaiala, sul da Índia, que nem sequer é língua indoeuropeia.